# mockMvc doesn't understand securityConfig with multiple Matchers

Tags: spring, spring-security, mockmvc

my security config:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/ticket/create")
                .access("hasAnyAuthority('MANAGER','EMPLOYEE')")
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**","/ticket/*")
                .access("isAuthenticated()")
                .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .and().formLogin().defaultSuccessUrl("/ticket/all", true)
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .and().csrf().disable();
```

As you can see, i have /ticket/* required any authentication, but before i have higher priority with /ticket/create to have only 2 roles availeable.

On a live server it works fine, but when i try to write test, returns 403 forbidden as if i don't have access.
My test:

```
@Test
    public void testTicketCreate() throws Exception {

        logger.info("Test: Create Ticket Page");
        mockMvc.perform(get("/ticket/create").with(user("user").password("123").roles("MANAGER")))
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(view().name("createTicket"));

    }
```

if i change test from /ticket/create to any other url like /ticket/{id} it will pass with the same user.

Comment: When you specify that a user had `.roles("MANAGER")` then that gives the user the authority `"ROLE_MANAGER"`. You configuration is looking for the authority `"MANAGER"`, not `"ROLE_MANAGER"`. You can change your test user to use `.authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("MANAGER"))`, and remove `.roles("MANAGER")`

Comment: yes that helped, thanks. You can write this as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify that a user has `.roles("MANAGER")` then that gives the user the equivalent authority `"ROLE_MANAGER"`.
You security configuration is looking for the authority `"MANAGER"`, not `"ROLE_MANAGER"`.
You can change your test user to use `.authorities(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("MANAGER"))`, instead of `.roles("MANAGER")`.